# Слишком большой размер файла после обработки cv2

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, cv2

Я пытаюсь выбрать все белые пиксели и заменить их на черные, а все черные - на белые. при перезаписи изображения на выходе получаю слишком большой размер файла.

```
def replace_pixels(fn:str):
    img = cv2.imread(fn)
    white = (255, 255, 255)
    black = (1, 0, 0)
    bgmask = np.all(img == black, axis=-1)
    fgmask = np.all(img == white, axis=-1)
    img[~bgmask] = black
    img[~fgmask] = white
    cv2.imwrite(fn, img)
```

Алгоритм работает, однако c 2 кб, после обработки изображение весит 12-16кб

Comment: А какое имя (а главное - расширение) у файла? Да, и результат получается правильный?

Comment: результат правильный, расширение - png

Comment: А покажите ещё что скажет `print(img.shape)` сразу после чтения файла и перед записью в файл.

Comment: Вполне возможно, что исходный файл имеет глубину цвета 1bpp (черно-белый), а вы в результате получаете 3-канальную 8-битную картинку. Из-за этого и разница в размерах.